# Converting a flex component w/images to bitmap

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I am trying to take images I am placing in a flex canvas component to a bitmap. I was able to get to the point where I'm not getting an error but then no image shows up and the image I save out as a jpg is blank. I imagine I'm not setting the bitmap data correctly but can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is the code where I am converting it to a bitmap:

```
var imageSnap:ImageSnapshot = ImageSnapshot.captureImage(_renderPop);
   var imageByteArray:ByteArray = imageSnap.data as ByteArray;
   var bLoader:Loader = new Loader();
   bLoader.loadBytes(imageByteArray);

   var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(500,500);
   bmd.draw(bLoader);

   var imgTest:Image = new Image();
   imgTest.source = bmd;
   _renderPop.renderCanvas.addChild(imgTest);



   var fileRef:FileReference = new FileReference();
   fileRef.save(bLoader, 'testImage.jpg');
```

_renderPop.renderCanvas is where I am placing the images.  Anybody see anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code:

```
var bLoader:Loader = new Loader();
bLoader.loadBytes(imageByteArray);
```

...you're assuming that the bytes are being loaded immediately; try putting an event listener on the loader as follows:

```
bLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);

private function completeHandler(event:Event):void
{
    // ... the rest of your code goes here
}
```

The **loadBytes** functions works like the **load** function in that they are both asynchronous processes so you'll need the event listener. It is a little counter-intuitive, and i've made the same mistake myself several times.

If that doesn't work, maybe leave out the **contentLoaderInfo** property, but the above should work...

Let me know if you come right :)

Comment: OK thanks, so that seems to get me a little farther. But now I am getting an invalid bitmapdata error.  Do you see anything else that I might need to do to capture the bitmapdata correctly?

Comment: Just to clarify, I am getting the invalid bitmapdata error on this line:

var imageSnap:ImageSnapshot = ImageSnapshot.captureImage(_renderPop.renderCanvas,150);

If I just use _renderPop then I don't get an error, but I get a blank bitmapImage.  _renderPop.renderCanvas is an mx:Canvas object. I can trace it out, it is there.

Comment: What exactly is this ImageSnapshot class you're using? Instead of using that component, try doing it manually... There's a very interesting blog post on InsideRIA for doing just this (and a lot more!)
http://insideria.com/2008/03/image-manipulation-in-flex.html

Does that help at all?

Comment: It does help a bit, I just went in an used a jpegEncoder. It is working better now, but the image I am getting is blank. So it must just be the bounds I am using to draw the bitmap.

Comment: It could also be that your component that you're trying to draw hasn't rendered correctly yet. When are you triggering the BitmapData.draw function? It'd add a FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE event on the component and then run the code... If this isn't the case, let me know

Answer (score 1):

Your "loader" code is wrong. Just after capturing image you may at once save data with FileReference:

```
var imageSnap:ImageSnapshot = ImageSnapshot.captureImage(_renderPop);
var fileRef:FileReference = new FileReference();    
fileRef.save(imageSnap.data, 'testImage.png');
```

That imageSnap contains not BitmapData but png image bytes. In order to show image you need to capture BitmapData but not image and create Bitmap from bitmap data:

```
var bmd:BitmapData = ImageSnapshot.captureBitmapData(_renderPop);
var imgTest:Image = new Image();
imgTest.source = new Bitmap(bmd);
_renderPop.renderCanvas.addChild(imgTest);
```

In result locally testImage.png is created on file system and it is shown in canvas. If you need jpg you should specify:

```
var imageSnap:ImageSnapshot = ImageSnapshot.captureImage(_renderPop, 0, new JPEGEncoder());
```